# Which one is faster get_headers() vs curl ()?

Tags: php, curl

I need to write a php script which will accept the csv file as input and then parse the product urls provided in it.

After then I need to validate which product url is exist and which is not.
I have got these two options for it `curl()` and `get_headers()`.

So can you please let me know which one is more faster and reliable ?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested this with 100 unique domains:

```
$urls = [
  "http://familyshare.com/",
  "http://elitedaily.com/",
  "http://www.pickthebrain.com/",
  "http://i100.independent.co.uk/",
  "http://thingsorganizedneatly.tumblr.com/",
  "http://www.cheatsheet.com/",
  "https://jet.com/",
  "https://nightwalk.withgoogle.com/en/panorama",
  "http://www.vumble.com/",
  "http://fusion.net/",
  "https://www.zozi.com",
  "http://joshworth.com/dev/pixelspace/pixelspace_solarsystem.html",
  "http://how-old.net/",
  "https://www.dosomething.org",
  "https://devart.withgoogle.com/",
  "http://www.ranker.com/",
  "http://the-toast.net/",
  "https://www.futurelearn.com/",
  "https://croaciaaudio.com/",
  "http://www.thesimpledollar.com/",
  "http://giphy.com/giphytv",
  "http://snapzu.com/",
  "https://www.touchofmodern.com/",
  "http://www.howstuffworks.com/",
  "http://www.sporcle.com/",
  "http://www.factcheck.org/",
  "https://www.privacytools.io/",
  "http://tiffanithiessen.com/",
  "http://www.supercook.com/",
  "http://www.livescience.com/",
  "http://www.freshnessmag.com",
  "http://www.abeautifulmess.com/",
  "http://cardboardboxoffice.com/",
  "http://www.takepart.com/",
  "http://www.fixya.com/",
  "http://bestreviews.com/",
  "http://theodysseyonline.com/",
  "http://justdelete.me/",
  "http://adventure.com/",
  "http://www.carryology.com/",
  "http://whattheysee.tumblr.com/",
  "https://unsplash.com/",
  "http://fromwhereidrone.com/",
  "http://www.attn.com/",
  "http://ourworldindata.org/",
  "http://www.melty.com/",
  "http://www.truthdig.com/",
  "https://tosdr.org/",
  "https://thinga.com/",
  "http://forvo.com/",
  "http://tiii.me/",
  "https://snapguide.com/",
  "http://www.tubefilter.com/",
  "http://www.inherentlyfunny.com/",
  "http://www.someecards.com/",
  "https://this.cm/",
  "http://littlebigdetails.com/",
  "http://clapway.com/",
  "http://www.nerdfitness.com/",
  "http://iwantdis.com/",
  "http://Racked.com",
  "http://thesweetsetup.com/",
  "http://www.we-heart.com/",
  "https://www.revealnews.org/",
  "https://featuredcreature.com/",
  "http://www.scotthyoung.com/blog/",
  "http://www.thehandandeye.com/",
  "http://www.thenorthernpost.com/",
  "http://www.welzoo.com/",
  "http://www.tickld.com/",
  "http://thinksimplenow.com/",
  "http://www.quietrev.com/",
  "http://www.freshoffthegrid.com/",
  "https://www.generosity.com/",
  "http://addicted2success.com/",
  "http://cubiclane.com/",
  "http://waitbutwhy.com/",
  "http://toolsandtoys.net/",
  "http://googling.co/",
  "http://penelopetrunk.com/",
  "http://iaf.tv/",
  "http://artofvisuals.com/",
  "http://www.lifeaftercollege.org/blog",
  "http://listverse.com/",
  "http://chrisguillebeau.com/",
  "http://expeditionportal.com/",
  "http://www.marieforleo.com/",
  "http://mostexclusivewebsite.com/",
  "http://www.alphr.com/",
  "http://www.rtings.com/",
  "http://all-that-is-interesting.com/",
  "http://theunbeatnpath.xyz/",
  "http://www.keepinspiring.me/",
  "https://paidtoexist.com/blog/",
  "http://www.lovethispic.com/",
  "http://riskology.co/blog/",
  "http://geyserofawesome.com/",
  "http://www.eugenewei.com/",
  "http://clickotron.com/"
];


$startTime = microtime(true);
  stream_context_set_default(
      array(
          'http' => array(
              'method' => 'HEAD'
          )
      )
  );
  $headers1 = [];
  foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $headers1[] = get_headers($url);
  }
$endTime = microtime(true);
$elapsed = $endTime - $startTime;
echo "Execution time : $elapsed seconds \n";


$startTime = microtime(true);
  $headers2 = [];
  foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
    $header2[] = curl_exec($ch);
  }
$endTime = microtime(true);
$elapsed = $endTime - $startTime;
echo "Execution time : $elapsed seconds \n";
```

**`get_headers`(GET) vs cURL**:

> Execution time : 139.95884609222 seconds
>   Execution time : 65.998840093613 seconds

**`get_headers`(HEAD) vs cURL**:

> Execution time : 114.60515785217 seconds
>   Execution time : 66.077962875366 seconds

So indeed cURL is *significantly* faster.

Comment: Is cURL faster if you're actually doing processes on the other end though?  With get_header you can object buffer the header and return it, then continue to do your data processing, where curl will wait for all the processing to be done before it returns.

Comment: also, in which order did you get (the _same_) urls. network latency probably beats processing. there is all kind of routing proxy caching going on which will obliterate valid results